# Does any of this cable connection data indicate an error with the incoming connection?

Tags: internet, cable-modem

Can someone tell me if the data from my cable modem seems to indicate a problem with the incoming connection?

Do the Frequency, Power and SNR values seem like they are in the expected range for a working connection?  Or do they (any one or more) indicate a problem?

Can you tell me what

1. Correctables means?
2. Uncorrectables?

Do either of those indicate a problem?  Can you explain what problem they might indicate?

[image: cable modem data]

Comment: Ask your ISP...

Comment: I already asked.

Comment: And what was their answer? Do you not believe it?

Comment: Oh,they never answered.  But I do believe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a hardware problem.
The tech arrived (after two days of waiting) went to the cable drop (at the back of the yard).
I explained how that suddenly we had no connection.

He went to the drop pulled the cable out of the box. He said, "Yep, there's an old filter on here.  He unscrewed the cable from the filter.  Screwed the cable directly into the main drop feed.

"That'll fix it.  The main office changed frequencies that the Internet signal is being sent on.  This old filter is a holdover from days when the video signal was separated from the Internet frequences.   When they changed frequencies you no longer received the signal because they were filtered out."

So if you see the type of values in your modem settings that I showed in the above question (image) this may help a little.